# How to get the count of a column greater than 1 wrt other column

Tags: r

Input:

| date | fruit | code | No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | Apple | 4052 | 1 |
| 2022-10-18 | Apple | 0216 | 3 |
| 2022-10-18 | Apple | 1444 | 4 |
| 2022-10-18 | Mango | 3442 | 1 |
| 2022-10-18 | Mango | 4152 | 6 |

Output : I want to calculate the count of No column greater than one wrt date & fruit

| date | fruit | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | Apple | 2 |
| 2022-10-18 | Mango | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(date, fruit) %>% 
 summarise(No = sum(No > 1))



date       fruit    No
  <chr>      <chr> <int>
1 2022-10-18 Apple     2
2 2022-10-18 Mango     1
```